# Compression algorithm on Unix Executables?

Tags: compression, executable

When I pop open a unix executable into a text editor, it's pretty obvious that the Machine code from the compiler has been compressed. Please correct me if I'm wrong about anything I say, but since it's compressed, what compression algorithm (zip, gzip etc.) Is the compiler (I used LLVM) using?

Comment: Just to clarify, it's not just the fact that it looks like gibberish in your text editor that leads you to conclude it's compressed, right?

Comment: What makes you think it's compressed?

Comment: Haha no, I've seen what the zip archiver program outputs as raw text a few times. And there's a clear method to the gibberish. This lead me to conclude that it's compressed. That and looking up if the llvm does compression.

Answer (score 2):

> When I pop open a unix **executable** into a text editor [...]

It depends on your flavor of UNIX, but nowadays UNIX executables are typically in [ELF format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format), which is uncompressed. You can manually compress them, of course, but then you cannot link or load them without decompressing them first. In any case, neither GCC not Clang will automatically compress their output binaries.

Also, it's not quite clear to me *why* you attempted to open an executable file in a text editor - if you want to take a look at the binary, you should be looking for a proper viewer for binary files, such as a [hex editor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor); if you want to see a more readable version of the code within, you should be using a [disassembler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disassembler).

Answer (score -2):

It's `bzip2`. It was implemented in llvm-ld v. 1.4:

Bytecode compression with bzip2 has been implemented. All bytecode files generated by LLVM will now be compressed by default. Compression can be disabled with the -disable-compression option to the tools that can generate bytecode files.

http://llvm.org/releases/1.4/docs/ReleaseNotes.html

Comment: Thanks, but adding the extension bzip2 to the end of a executable generated by the LLVM to get the machine code. So is there anything else I need to do to get the Machine code?

Comment: Don't confuse between bytecode and binary executable. If i remember correctly, the bytecode is just a compact representation of the IR code generated along the way, not the final binary.